# Can I use my leftover green board as furring strips behind shower surround?

Tags: bathroom, shower

In bathroom.  Putting in  new shower surround.  I removed more layers equaling more depth than putting back, so I need to add furring strips to make green board be at correct spot on tub. Question: can I use my leftover green board for the furring strips? So it would be stud, furring strip (green board), green board, shower surround.  Please and thank you

Comment: I would not although. Have seen it done. if screwed in green board tends to crumble like Sheetrock. Glued on I have seen hold up better but I prefer to to use wood. Left as a comment as this is an opinion question.

Comment: I strongly recommend against using greenboard for tub/shower surrounds. Concrete or tile backer board only, even when covering with a fiberglass insert. Nevertheless, I would not use greenboard strips for furring strips even if I did use greenboard, use wood of the required thickness or sister to the wall studs if the gap is large ( > 1")